# SQL query in php using randoma and where clause error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query in SQL to fetch data using PHP. The query is as below:

```
$response=mysqli_query($con,"select * from haad WHERE id =(select min(id) from questions where id > {$_POST['next_id']}) ORDER BY RAND() ");
```

Evrything is working fine except, I can't get random data using this. Data shows in the same order. What is the error in this code?

Comment: what  was the error ..?

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour. Can you?

Comment: @Dr.Strange random questions are not displaying, same questions are showing

Comment: @Strawberry i didnt get you

Comment: can you pls share your database data

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: try with this : `SELECT * FROM haad  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM questions  WHERE > {$_POST['next_id']}) ORDER BY RAND()
`

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM haad WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM questions WHERE id > ' " .$_POST['next_id'] ." ' ORDER BY RAND())"

Comment: ($con,"select * from haad WHERE id =(select min(id) from haad where id > {$_POST['next_id']})"); this is the query. can you edit this

Comment: syntax. the braces in ur query is not set properly

Comment: store the value of $_POST['next_id'] in a variable like $id and then run :
select * from haad WHERE id =(select min(id) from questions where id > $id) ORDER BY RAND(), should work

Comment: can you give me ur mail